# neo4j servlet concurrent access

Tags: servlets, neo4j

Can I open a neo4j database using

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( A_CERTAIN_PATH );
```

in many different servlets, or I can't access to the same db from two different java processes?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you can't access the same database from two different processes, if you try to do so you'll get a lock exception saying that your database is already opened.

You should use a class with a static reference to the database and use this class to get instance of your database every time you need it (queries ..)

Comment: So the only wai to access concurrently to the same database from different threads at the same time is to use rest apis ?

Comment: What kind of server are you using ? embedded or not ?

Comment: embedded. But I figured out a simple solution that is: make a static GraphDatabaseService class by initializing it in a ServletContextListener. The any servlet that want to use it just have to context.getAttribute("that_class")

Comment: Yes that's the idea but be careful about the operations you'll make later on this class, they should be thread safe with synchronized key word

Comment: Yes i know. But i read that this class is intrinsically thread safe. Should i care about synchronization also in this case ?

Comment: My mistake you're using GraphDatabaseService,so no problem